# Can we wrap/ modify Cordova FS APIs with Node APIs by Electron to make them work under Desktop environment?

Tags: node.js, cordova, electron

I am having an angular/ionic app that builds upon cordova for multiple mobile platforms. Now I want to extend it to desktop. I have run the web view folder(`www/`) in electron and everything is working fine except some cordova File System APIs.

Is there a way for me, so that I can wrap/modify those cordova APIs using Node FS APIs provided in electron ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [cordova-electron](https://github.com/apache/cordova-electron) project by Apache but there's little documentation. I don't know of any other similar project.

Most probably you'd have to abstract away your FS API calls and create your own functions that do what they need in both environments. You are likely to also have some other differences in the filesystem layout to take into account.

For example if you want to read files and save files, you can create two functions:

```
readFile(name, callback) {
  if (RUNNING_IN_ELECTRON) {
    // use Node API
  } else {
    // use Cordova API
  }
}

writeFile(name, data, callback) {
  if (RUNNING_IN_ELECTRON) {
    // use Node API
  } else {
    // use Cordova API
  }
}
```

You can either detect that you're running in Electron e.g. by testing for `process.versions['electron']` or alternatively you can test if you're running in Cordova, e.g. testing for `window.cordova`.